# confidence interval and prediction interval in SAS

Tags: sas

Given the model:

```
 Y = b0 + b1 x1 + b2 x2 + b3 x3
```

what command in SAS will allow me to see the confidence interval for Y?

Comment: Depends on which PROC you're using. As stated there isn't enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc reg; model y=x1 x2 x3;
```

see online for output details.